# UITableView Custom View still here even after reload

Tags: objective-c

I made a very simply table view, with load more function.
I have added a custom view on the last cell with text "Load More"
After the user clicked the load more function, the rows increased successfully.
But the text "Load More" didn't disappear.
Please help.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    noRow = 10;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return noRow+1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.row != noRow ) { // As long as we haven’t reached the +1 yet in the count, we populate the cell like normal
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:[indexPath row]] stringValue];

    cell.text = cellValue;
    } // Ok, all done for filling the normal cells, next we probaply reach the +1 index, which doesn’t contain anything yet

    else if(indexPath.row == noRow ) { // Here we check if we reached the end of the index, so the +1 row
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        UILabel *loadMore;

        loadMore =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];
        loadMore.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        loadMore.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        loadMore.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        loadMore.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20];
        loadMore.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        loadMore.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        loadMore.text=@"Load More..";
        [cell addSubview:loadMore];


    }        
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == noRow){
        NSLog(@"noRow Prev: %d", noRow);
        noRow += 5;
        NSLog(@"noRow After: %d", noRow);
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"IndexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the and you are not removing the view that you have added for load more

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [[cell viewWithTag:121] removeFromSuperview];//remove this tag view
    if (indexPath.row != noRow ) { // As long as we haven’t reached the +1 yet in the count, we populate the cell like normal
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Set up the cell...
        NSString *cellValue = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:[indexPath row]] stringValue];

        cell.text = cellValue;
    } // Ok, all done for filling the normal cells, next we probaply reach the +1 index, which doesn’t contain anything yet

    else if(indexPath.row == noRow ) { // Here we check if we reached the end of the index, so the +1 row
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        UILabel *loadMore;

        loadMore =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];
        loadMore.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        loadMore.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        loadMore.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        loadMore.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20];
        loadMore.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        loadMore.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        loadMore.text=@"Load More..";
        loadMore.tag = 121;// just setting the tag
        [cell addSubview:loadMore];


    }        
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped.
For other people having this problem, just add 2 rows with .tag inside the above code.

Answer (score 1):

you should add `loadMore` as a subview to `cell.contentView` not cell.

after that add this line in your cellForRow ..

```
  for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Currently your load more is being reused and is present in subsequent cells if reused.